# No sound coming out of headphones

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers, headphones

After installing Windows 8 there is no sound coming out of headphones *in Windows*, but it seems to work fine in Ubuntu (dual-boot).

In Realtek HD Manager it shows that headphones are connected:

[image: 1]

When I plug the headphones in it also says that I connected them:

[image: 2]

but still no sound is coming out. what can be the problem?

P.S. After installing Windows 8, I've installed just Realtek HD driver from Asus' website, the remaining drivers are installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the sound icon in your taskbar and go to "playback devices". Right click on your headphones and click "Set as default device"

Comment: that is what i have http://s14.directupload.net/images/130715/chb4j6iq.jpg seems to be enabled.

Comment: Do the bars beside that device animate (turn green/red) when you play sound?

Comment: yes, they do #shortcomment

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the levels/enhancements/advanced tab?

Comment: yep, here they are: http://s7.directupload.net/images/130715/jhb5czw2.jpg
http://s7.directupload.net/images/130715/vxtxflyc.jpg
http://s14.directupload.net/images/130715/umhnvdj6.jpg

Comment: Is there any reason you downloaded the audio driver from ASUS's website? You may want to completely remove all your sound drivers and let Windows install all drivers.